# Zerb Foundation 3 - IE7 Fix not working?

Tags: html, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, responsive-design, modernizr

I am having an issue getting the IE7 fix for Zerb Foundation 3 ([found HERE](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/making-zurb-foundation-3-work-on-ie7/))

I have changed the following:

```
 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  *behavior: url(../javascripts/boxsizing.htc); 
}
```

as well as:

```
.button.dropdown > ul {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box; *behavior: url(../javascripts/boxsizing.htc); 
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-top: none;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 40;
}
```

Yet it is still not rednering properly in IE7 according to my adobe browserlab test, now im not sure if its just a browserlab issue as I cant run IE7.

I have also tried to include [Modernizr's no-box-sizing](http://modernizr.com/download/#-cssclasses-addtest-css_boxsizing) which is still implemented but also does not seem to be helping.

You can [view the site HERE](http://tst.eclipsecreative.ca/ebc3462/home/).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I launch your site in browser stack it crashes the browser. Ideas?

Comment: @justinavery I have FIXED the IE crashing problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: I think I have it solved. This foundation is running on a very basic wordpress theme (as a framework) I am using a child theme so I ended up adding the *behavior: url(../javascripts/boxsizing.htc); to the child theme's .css file and I think it is fine now. If someone can confirm that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I was using foundation converted to wordpress and I included the above at the top of my style.css for my theme and it worked for me.